# Yup oneOf TypeScript Enum Generic Fucntion

Tags: typescript, enums, yup

I cannot figure out the correct types for a function that generates a `yup` schema for `oneOf` with TypeScript enums.

---

The follow works as expected and has a return type of `yup.MixSchema<SomeEnum>`

```
const schema1 = yup.mixed<SomeEnum>().oneOf(Object.values(SomeEnum)); // yup.MixSchema<SomeEnum>
```

---

If I try to make a generic function to return the schema I get the return type of `yup.MixSchema<typeof SomeEnum>`. Notice the `typeof`.

```
const oneOfEnum = <T>(enumObject: T) =>
  yup.mixed<T>().oneOf(Object.values(enumObject));

const schema2 = oneOfEnum(SomeEnum); // yup.MixSchema<typeof SomeEnum>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/yup-typescript-oneof-enum-vpvjn?file=/src/index.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix this like so (change the argument type to match the argument for `Object.values`):

```js
const oneOfEnum = <T>(enumObject: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>) =>
  yup.mixed<T>().oneOf(Object.values(enumObject));
```