# generic enum parsing in yup 1.0.0

Tags: typescript, validation, enums, yup

we are currently on yup 0.32.11. in order to create a generic enum parser, we have been using the following

```
export const oneOfEnum = <T>(enumObject: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>) =>
  Yup.mixed<T>().oneOf(Object.values(enumObject));
```

this was taken from this question [Yup oneOf TypeScript Enum Generic Fucntion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62177877/yup-oneof-typescript-enum-generic-fucntion), but no longer works in the newest version of yup

with 1.0.0, this shows the error: `Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'AnyPresentValue'`

I cannot figure out the proper incantation for this...part of this is that I'm not really sure how to represent enums in typescript's generics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into [yup type definitions](https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/f37a53f45048eefe445c14b27b1b031583f9585d/src/mixed.ts#L24), you can see that generic argument of `yup.mixed` must extend `AnyPresentValue` type, which is an alias for `{}` type.

Solution would be to also mark your generic parameter as extending `{}`:

```js
export const oneOfEnum = <T extends {}>(
  enumObject: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>,
) => yup.mixed<T>().oneOf(Object.values(enumObject));
```

If you want to be more strict and match your enum values more closely, you can use `string` instead of `{}` (or `number`, depends on your enum values).

```js
export const oneOfEnum = <T extends string>(
  enumObject: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>,
) => yup.mixed<T>().oneOf(Object.values(enumObject));
```